# Reasons for using default logic

Tags: logic

I can see the obvious reasons for using default logic but I would like to have a **full list** of the reasons including the not so obvious ones .
what is the motivation behind default logic?
why can't we use the classical form of logic? etc.. 
by "default logic" I am referring to the non-monotonic logic proposed by Raymond Reiter.

Comment: See [Default logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_logic) as well as the paper by Reiter: [A Logic for Default Reasoning](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/G52HPA/articles/Reiter:80a.pdf).

Comment: Already did. looking for something more elaborated and exhaustive.

Comment: You can try with Philippe Besnard, [An Introduction to Default Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=npGqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR9) (1989).

Comment: that was really helpful but still feels like I need something more detailed. thank you!